# How to set sample weight in sklearn logistic regression?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a problem when I do the logistic regression in `scikit learn` python package.

When the data it has a different number of samples for 1 or 0, I want to do logistic regression with concerning sample weight. But, I have a few data, so I can't get the same number of samples for each.

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) of sklearn's LogisticRegression says, there are two options to assign weights to samples.

The classifier accepts a `class_weight` parameter which can be used to set the weight of all samples belonging to a certain class. One can also apply `class_weight='balanced'` to automatically adjust the class weights based on the number of samples in each class.

The `fit` method of the classifier also accepts a `sample_weight` array which assigns weights to individual samples.